# Is there any technical bar from restarting the nuclear power plants of Germany?

Tags: renewable-energy, nuclear-technology

Any that makes it impractical or, yet worse, impossible?

If no, how long should it take for Germany to get them back online?

Comment: Closed due to age? So time travel??

Comment: And how is nuclear a "renewable"?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably better worded as "green-technology", and not renewable. The closing didn't occur "due to age" though, it occurred apparently due to Siemens refusing to do anything with nuclear, probably including their necessary maintenance. The power plants are renewable though — with the right know-how, they could be renewed, and used during a transition to renewables and the hoped-for rise of fusion plants. Still better than going back to fossils power plants as a result of the war.

Comment: Since they are in the process of *decommission and dismantle* a lot of sites and public are against nuclear since Fukushima accident in Japan, despite lots of coal generation, the answer is never.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat "Eight of the seventeen operating reactors in Germany were permanently shut down following the March 2011 Fukushima nuclear disaster" Although, that's not the question, is it?

Comment: And some of the news was about the managers wanting to extend the operating time past the original dates.

Comment: @SolarMike which is exactly what you do with any constructions. Set a date, then you thoroughly review it when you get close to that date because that date initially needs to be set conservatively to ensure security. Then you find what would prevent the extension, if anything, set out a plan to address it, and a date how long operation could be extended by addressing those issues. 

Does this look any good to you? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Energymix_Germany.svg/2560px-Energymix_Germany.svg.png

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh should check out Chernobyl…

Comment: Natural gas in the energy mix of Germany tripled (!) in the past ten years, congrats to all the greenmongers. Now that gas will not be enough for even heating, about a sixth of the whole energy mix will be in jeopardy. Nuclear would be the least global-warming inducing alternative that could immediately pick up at this scale.

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh, please keep comments polite. For sarcasm and rants you'll need to find another site. See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/conduct.

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh Hence a comment.  If they are all slated to shut down at the end of 22, then the ones still operating can be easily extended.  But once shutdown (any industry), it is hard and expensive to restart.

Comment: Nuclear energy is the most complicated way humans have devised to boil water. As for the nuclear power stations in Germany, it depends on how far into the decommissioning process each plant is & also on the type of type of nuclear power plant, some plants are more complicated than others.

Comment: @Transistor polite and not sarcastic? You mean this comment: “Closed due to age? So time travel??” Ha-ha-ha, heat,

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh, I think your comments I am referring to have been deleted since I commented.

Comment: @SolarMike now we have gas as sustainable: https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/eu-parliament-set-for-cliff-edge-vote-on-green-investments/2022/07/06/7cbc7e02-fd00-11ec-b39d-71309168014b_story.html

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is technically keeping nuclear plants from re-starting.  Clearly technology exists to rebuild even partially dismantled plants.  What does not exist in the wake of Fukushima is the political will to operate these units in Germany.

Comment: Do you have any specific knowledge of examples that a layman would understand relative to the technical impracticability or impossibility, too? And the time it would take maybe through a few example of these plants or any more specific numbers?

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh no, but anything that has been unbuilt can be rebuilt.  That parts that really matter, like the pressure vessel, are usually left for lter to let the residual radioactivity decay.